# an ODE system that i have never senn again neither i have learned a way to solve it

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\Bigg\{
\begin{array}{cc}
\dot{x(t)}={5x(t)\over 100}(1-{y(t)\over 100})\\
\dot{y(t)}={y(t)\over 10}({5x(t)\over 1000}-2)
\end{array}$$

The only progress that i may have made is, if you combine the two equations you got
$$\dot{y(t)}+\dot{x(t)}={-2y(t)\over10}+{5x(t)\over 100}$$
so there is not x*y term but you have only one equation for two functions

Comment: Firstly, welcome! 
Try to rearrange the initial equations by combining similar terms. Moreover, your sum is wrong. Where did you take that from?

Comment: thank you for wlecoming me, the sum came from adding the two equation 
$$\dot{y(t)}+\dot{x(t)}={y(t)\over10}({5x(t)\over 1000}-2)+{5x(t)\over 100}(1-{y(t)\over 100}) \implies$$
$$\dot{y(t)}+\dot{x(t)}={5y(t)x(t)\over 10*1000}-{2y(t)\over 10}+{5x(t)\over 100}-{5x(t)y(t)\over 1000} \implies$$
$$\dot{y(t)}+\dot{x(t)}={-2y(t)\over10}+{5x(t)\over 100}$$
Your sugestion is to replace $y(t)$ from fist equation and $x(t)$ from the second ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the **Lotka–Volterra predator–prey equations**, which you can easily find information about on the internet, for example on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations).

There are no explicit solution formulas for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ in terms of elementary functions, but there is a constant of motion $F(x,y)$ which shows that the solution curves (in the positive quadrant) are closed curves.